# Top Custom tabs bar displaying today and 1 week dates

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabs

A beginner in iOS Objective C, I need to some help to create a custom tab as shown in the pic.

[image: Custom Tab]

The custom tab will show today's plus 6 days date. Then when user click on the dates, it will call a uRL. I need some pointers if possible. All help is highly appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: [The answer using button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306331/dates-in-custom-tab-bar-button-not-showing)
Using button to create the tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some third-party segmented controls. For Objective-C is could be [this](https://github.com/cwRichardKim/RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers) or [this](https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNSegmentedControl), then you get 6 next dates from current date, for example this code adds 1 day to current date and etc.:

```
NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
dayComponent.day = 1;

NSCalendar *theCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *nextDate = [theCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

NSLog(@"nextDate: %@ ...", nextDate);
```