# ObjectiveC - WebView not reloading from the top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uirefreshcontrol

I have a `webpage` which has a long list of items. I want the user to refresh the page when they tapped on the tab bar item. I manage to call the method to load the web view when they tapped the tab bar item. But it just doesn't reload afresh from the top. It seems like `webview` is loading from where it is or cache or something. I tried to `removecahce` but it doesn't seems to work. I want it to reload afresh from the top again. I can't use `viewWillAppear` because I don't want the page to reload when it is back from the `detail` page. And I also want the page to reload when the tab bar item is being tapped.

Reload at where you browse, I need to reload afresh from all the way from the top.

[image: Long list]

**MyTabBarController.m**

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if([viewController isKindOfClass:[ClassNavigationController class]]) {
        Classes *myClasses = [[Classes alloc] init];
        [myClasses reloadWebView];
    }
}
```

**Classes.m**

```
- (void)LoadClasses {
    sURL = @"www.longlist.com"

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:sURL];
    sRefresh = sURL;
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
    [webView setDelegate:(id<UIWebViewDelegate>)self];

    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [webView.scrollView addSubview:refreshControl];
}
//=== Not Working
-(void)reloadWebView{
    [webView reload];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could scroll the webView to top by setting it's content inset to CGPointZero while loading it.

Here's the code:

```
[webview.scrollView setContentInset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
```

Comment: Not working, I get this error: Sending 'CGPoint' (aka 'struct CGPoint') to parameter of incompatible type 'UIEdgeInsets' (aka 'struct UIEdgeInsets')

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for can be acheieved with the help of  **Delegate Protocols**.

First go through the [Docs!](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html) for better understanding of the concept.

Now the code, head to your  **MyTabBarController.h** file and add the following code.

```
@protocol reloadWeb<NSObject>  // The reloadWeb is our protocol and can be named as you like
-(void)reloadWebViewData;    // This is the method to be called on the location you want the reload function to be called
@end

@interface MyTabBarController : UITabBarController

@property(nonatomic,assign)id<reloadWeb> reloadDelegate; // Here we create an object for the protocol.
```

Then on **MyTabBarController.m**, and update the `didSelectViewController` method like below

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[newViewController class]]) { // Here newViewController is the controller where the webview reload happens.
        [[[newViewController alloc] init] reloadWebViewData];  // We create and instance for the new controller and call the delegate method where the reload works.
    }
}
```

Now **newViewController.h**

```
#import "MyTabBarController.h"

@interface newViewController : UIViewController<reloadWeb>  // Here we have to confirm the protocol "reloadWeb" we created in order to access the delegate method

@end
```

Finally on **newViewController.m**

```
#import "newViewController.h"
#import "MyTabBarController.h"

@interface newViewController ()

@end

@implementation newViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

/*We have to assgin delegate to tab controller where protocol is defined so from there the "reloadWebViewData" method can be called*/
    MyTabBarController * tab = [[MyTabBarController alloc] init];
    tab.reloadDelegate = self;    

}

-(void)reloadWebViewData{ 
    NSLog(@"Reload Webview Data here ");
}
```

> If you miss to add the above method ("**reloadWebViewData**") the Xcode will show a warning to confirm for the Protocol "reloadWeb" as the delegate method is missing.

Cheers!

Comment: can you please take a look at this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52293432/objective-c-how-to-properly-set-didselectviewcontroller-method-for-tabbarcontro/52299231#52299231

Comment: Yes went through your question and i think the above mentioned solution will work fine cause its working for me!